# What are the 'ref' and 'sealed' keywords in C++?

Tags: c++, ref, sealed

I've just seen some (presumably) C++ code which sports two "keywords" unknown to me (I'm assuming keywords but, since I have no context, they may be simple `#define` things).

They also don't seem to appear in the C++11 standard, at least the draft I have but, since that's a pretty late draft, I can't imagine them being just dropped into the standard at the last minute. They are `ref` and `sealed`.

The code I found them in was something like:

```
public ref class DevIface sealed {
    private:
        int currOffset;
public:
        DevIface (int initOffset);
        : : :
```

Does anyone know what these keywords are, and what they're meant to achieve?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is C++/CLI.

A [`ref class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/ref-classes-and-structs-c-cx) is a managed type.
`sealed` means that the class cannot be inherited

Comment: These keywords also used with native C++ WinRT APIs for Windows 8.

Comment: A ref class in WinRT means it is a ref-counted type that can be used across ABI (application binary interface) calls.

Answer (score 9):

Thus summary is that "ref" and "sealed" are not standard C++ keywords. They are used in microsoft version.

Answer (score 7):

`sealed` in C++/CLI is roughly equivalent to `final` in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in the new C++/CX use of these keywords to project WinRT APIs into MS Visual C++, you may enjoy this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-532T with these slides: http://video.ch9.ms/build/2011/slides/TOOL-532T_Sutter.pptx . See esp. slides 8-13.  There are other talks with yet more information referenced on slide 29.